# For Loop - Return first 2 instead of all

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html("website" . date("Ymd")); 

foreach($html->find('td[class=x]') as $element) 
       echo $element;
?>
```

I am using the above code to parse a website. Instead of returning all the td elements I would like to return the first two. I think I would need to edit the for loop. How can I do this. I have limited PHP experience.

Comment: maybe just shortciruit the loop, if its on the second, break it, just directly point it to two, find(element, 0) and 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique would be to use a counter

```
   $counter = 0;
    foreach ($html->find('td[class=x]') as $element) {
        if($counter<=1){
            echo $element;
        }
        $counter++;
    }
```